# Complex cumulative sum with double resets

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I'm trying to follow some rules about when to group data to chart.
How would I go from this data frame:

```
# A tibble: 11 x 8
   assay      year   qtr invalid valid total_assays    hfr predicted_inv
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>         <dbl>
 1 test_case 2016.    1.      2.   36.          38. 0.0350         1.33 
 2 test_case 2016.    2.      1.   34.          35. 0.0350         1.23 
 3 test_case 2016.    3.      0.   25.          25. 0.0350         0.875
 4 test_case 2016.    4.      2.   23.          25. 0.0350         0.875
 5 test_case 2017.    1.      1.   29.          30. 0.0350         1.05 
 6 test_case 2017.    2.      2.   24.          26. 0.0350         0.910
 7 test_case 2017.    3.      0.   23.          23. 0.0350         0.805
 8 test_case 2017.    4.      1.   20.          21. 0.0350         0.735
 9 test_case 2018.    1.      2.   33.          35. 0.0350         1.23 
10 test_case 2018.    2.      5.   28.          33. 0.0350         1.16 
11 test_case 2018.    3.      4.    9.          13. 0.0350         0.455
```

To this one:

```
       assay year qtr invalid valid total_assays   hfr predicted_inv co_inv co_val co_prd_inv trend
1  test_case 2016   1       2    36           38 0.035         1.330      2     36      1.330    No
2  test_case 2016   2       1    34           35 0.035         1.225      3     70      2.555    No
3  test_case 2016   3       0    25           25 0.035         0.875      3     95      3.430    No
4  test_case 2016   4       2    23           25 0.035         0.875      5    118      4.305   Yes
5  test_case 2017   1       1    29           30 0.035         1.050      1     29      1.050    No
6  test_case 2017   2       2    24           26 0.035         0.910      3     53      1.960    No
7  test_case 2017   3       0    23           23 0.035         0.805      3     76      2.765    No
8  test_case 2017   4       1    20           21 0.035         0.735      4     96      3.500    No
9  test_case 2018   1       2    33           35 0.035         1.225      6    129      4.725   Yes
10 test_case 2018   2       5    28           33 0.035         1.155      5     28      1.155   Yes
11 test_case 2018   3       4     9           13 0.035         0.455      4      9      0.455    No
```

The rules are fairly simple. For each row, if the cumulative sum of either invalid or predicted_inv is 5 or greater, then trend is 'yes' and the cumulative sums of all three parameters (invalid, valid, predicted_inv) are reset and start again from the next row. In the end the groupings (co_*) would be trended.

I've tried some solutions using dplyr, but I keep getting errors when I try to create multiple interdependent variables at the same time.

Now I'm trying a custom function that takes just the 3 parameters as vectors, but I keep being forced to build loops... I would prefer an easy to read dplyr solution.

Here are the dputs:

```
egdf1 <- structure(list(assay = c("test_case", "test_case", "test_case", 
                         "test_case", "test_case", "test_case", "test_case", "test_case", 
                         "test_case", "test_case", "test_case"), year = c(2016, 2016, 
                                                                          2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2017, 2018, 2018, 2018), qtr = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                         2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3), invalid = c(2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 1, 2, 5, 4), valid = c(36, 34, 25, 23, 29, 24, 23, 20, 33, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              28, 9), total_assays = c(38, 35, 25, 25, 30, 26, 23, 21, 35, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       33, 13), hfr = c(0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035), predicted_inv = c(1.33, 1.225, 0.875, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.875, 1.05, 0.91, 0.805, 0.735, 1.225, 1.155, 0.455)), .Names = c("assay", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "year", "qtr", "invalid", "valid", "total_assays", "hfr", "predicted_inv"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -11L))

egdf2 <- structure(list(assay = c("test_case", "test_case", "test_case", 
                         "test_case", "test_case", "test_case", "test_case", "test_case", 
                         "test_case", "test_case", "test_case"), year = c(2016L, 2016L, 
                                                                          2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2017L, 2018L, 2018L, 2018L
                         ), qtr = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), invalid = c(2L, 
                                                                                             1L, 0L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 4L), valid = c(36L, 34L, 
                                                                                                                                                25L, 23L, 29L, 24L, 23L, 20L, 33L, 28L, 9L), total_assays = c(38L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              35L, 25L, 25L, 30L, 26L, 23L, 21L, 35L, 33L, 13L), hfr = c(0.035, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 0.035, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0.035), predicted_inv = c(1.33, 1.225, 0.875, 0.875, 1.05, 0.91, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.805, 0.735, 1.225, 1.155, 0.455), co_inv = c(2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 4L), co_val = c(36L, 70L, 95L, 118L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          29L, 53L, 76L, 96L, 129L, 28L, 9L), co_prd_inv = c(1.33, 2.555, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             3.43, 4.305, 1.05, 1.96, 2.765, 3.5, 4.725, 1.155, 0.455), trend = c("No", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             )), .Names = c("assay", "year", "qtr", "invalid", "valid", "total_assays", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            "hfr", "predicted_inv", "co_inv", "co_val", "co_prd_inv", "trend"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         ), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the function `cumsumbinning` from the MESS package to set up the value of the threshold that the cumulative group sum must not cross  (5 in your example). Please bear in mind that in row 9 because adding 2 to 4 crosses the threshold of 5 creates another group, while in your desired output you want that reset in the next row.

```
library(MESS)  
  egdf1 %>%
  group_by(group = cumsumbinning(invalid, 5)) %>%
  mutate(
    co_inv = cumsum(invalid),
    co_val = cumsum(valid),
    co_prd_inv = cumsum(predicted_inv),
    trend = ifelse(group - lag(group, default = 0) > 1, "yes", "no")
  )
```

**Output**

```
   assay      year   qtr invalid valid total_assays   hfr predicted_inv group co_inv co_val co_prd_inv trend
   <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>        <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl> <int>  <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>
 1 test_case  2016     1       2    36           38 0.035         1.33      1      2     36      1.33  no   
 2 test_case  2016     2       1    34           35 0.035         1.23      1      3     70      2.56  no   
 3 test_case  2016     3       0    25           25 0.035         0.875     1      3     95      3.43  no   
 4 test_case  2016     4       2    23           25 0.035         0.875     1      5    118      4.30  no   
 5 test_case  2017     1       1    29           30 0.035         1.05      2      1     29      1.05  yes  
 6 test_case  2017     2       2    24           26 0.035         0.91      2      3     53      1.96  no   
 7 test_case  2017     3       0    23           23 0.035         0.805     2      3     76      2.76  no   
 8 test_case  2017     4       1    20           21 0.035         0.735     2      4     96      3.5   no   
 9 test_case  2018     1       2    33           35 0.035         1.23      3      2     33      1.23  yes  
10 test_case  2018     2       5    28           33 0.035         1.16      4      5     28      1.16  yes  
11 test_case  2018     3       4     9           13 0.035         0.455     5      4      9      0.455 yes
```

Comment: Thanks, but the output needs to be exactly as in my 2nd data frame. ie. 2+4 = 6, and that's ok to summarize the data for the quarter, but then since these data have been trended, the next quarter starts fresh. Thanks for your answer anyway because it could always be helpful in the future!

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution using `Reduce`:

```
cs <- Reduce(function(x, y) if (max(x[1], x[3]) < 5) x + y else y,
             Map(c, egdf1$invalid, egdf1$valid, egdf1$predicted_inv),
             accumulate = TRUE)

co <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, cs)
names(co) <- c("co_inv", "co_val", "co_prd_inv")

co$trend <- ifelse(pmax(co$co_inv, co$co_prd_inv) >= 5, "Yes", "No")

all.equal(cbind(egdf1, co), egdf2)
# [1] TRUE
```