# Cumulative sum with reset option if multiple conditions are met

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to make a cumulative sum with reset option if multiple conditions are met. More specifically, I want to cumulative sum the variables `amount` and `count` grouped by `id` and reset/start from 0 again if these two conditions are met: `amount` >= 10 and `count` >= 3. I also would like to create a new column that contains 1 if these conditions are met and 0 otherwise.

Data sample:

```
df <- data.frame(
    date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01")),
    id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
    amount = c(1, 9, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 5, 5, 5),
    count = c(0, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0)
)
```

Desired output:

```
df <- data.frame(
    date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01")),
    id = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"),
    amount = c(1, 9, 5, 5, 6, 2, 10, 4, 8, 10, 6, 5, 5, 1, 6, 5, 5, 5),
    count = c(0, 2, 5, 4, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0),
    amount_cumsum = c(1, 10, 15, 5, 11, 2, 10, 14, 22, 32, 38, 43, 5, 6, 12, 5, 10, 5),
    count_cumsum = c(0, 2, 7, 4, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 0),
    condition_met = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0)
)
```

If possible, I would like a `dplyr` solution, but alternatives are also welcome. Thanks!

Update: an answer that was deleted by the author almost got the problem solved:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        amount_cumsum = purrr::accumulate(.x = amount, .f = ~ if_else(condition = .x < 10, true = .x + .y, false = .y)),
        count_cumsum = purrr::accumulate(.x = count, .f = ~ if_else(condition = .x < 3, true = .x + .y, false = .y)),
        condition_met = as.integer(amount_cumsum >= 10 & count_cumsum >= 3)
 )
```

Or, alternatively:

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(
        amount_cumsum = purrr::accumulate(.x = amount, .f = ~ case_when(.x < 10 ~ .x + .y, TRUE ~ .y)),
        count_cumsum = purrr::accumulate(.x = count, .f = ~ case_when(.x < 3 ~ .x + .y, TRUE ~ .y)),
        condition_met = as.integer(amount_cumsum >= 10 & count_cumsum >= 3)
    )
```

The answer above resets the cumulative sum if the condition is met for one single variable, but not taking into account if the other condition was met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contributing with a base-R solution:

```
df$amount_cumsum <- 0
df$count_cumsum <- 0    
df$condition_met <- 0  
reset = F
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  if (i == 1 | reset) {
    df$amount_cumsum[i] = df$amount[i]
    df$count_cumsum[i] = df$count[i]
    reset = F
  } else if (df$id[i] != df$id[i-1]) {
    df$amount_cumsum[i] = df$amount[i]
    df$count_cumsum[i] = df$count[i]
    reset = F
  } else {
    df$amount_cumsum[i] = df$amount_cumsum[i-1] + df$amount[i]
    df$count_cumsum[i] = df$count_cumsum[i-1] + df$count[i]
  }
  
  if (df$amount_cumsum[i] >= 10 & df$count_cumsum[i] >= 3) {
    df$condition_met[i] = 1
    reset = T
  }
}
```

I've expanded your dataset and benchmarked this code against [your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817328/cumulative-sum-with-reset-option-if-multiple-conditions-are-met/62855940#62855940). Benchmark shows the Base-R solution **21 times faster** than the tidyverse one!

```
library(tidyverse)

dates = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-03-04"), by="days")

df <- data.frame(
  date = c(sample(dates, 300), sample(dates, 400), sample(dates, 350)),
  id = c(rep("A", 300), rep("B", 400), rep("C", 350)),
  amount = floor(runif(1050, 0, 15)),
  count = floor(runif(1050, 0, 5)),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

rbenchmark::benchmark(
  "Tidy Solution" = {
    df_tidy <- df %>%
      group_by(id) %>%
      nest(data = c(amount, count)) %>%
      mutate(
        data_accumulate = purrr::accumulate(.x = data, .f = function(.x, .y) if (max(.x[1]) < 10 | max(.x[2]) < 3) .x + .y else .y)
      ) %>%
      unnest(cols = c(data_accumulate)) %>%
      rename(amount_cumsum = amount, count_cumsum = count) %>%
      unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
      mutate(condition_met = case_when(
        amount_cumsum >= 10 & count_cumsum >= 3 ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0)
      )
  },
  "Base-R Solution" = {
    df_base <- df
    df_base$amount_cumsum <- 0
    df_base$count_cumsum <- 0    
    df_base$condition_met <- 0  
    reset = F  # to reset the counters
    for (i in 1:nrow(df_base)) {
      if (i == 1 | reset) {
        df_base$amount_cumsum[i] = df_base$amount[i]
        df_base$count_cumsum[i] = df_base$count[i]
        reset = F
      } else if (df_base$id[i] != df_base$id[i-1]) {
        df_base$amount_cumsum[i] = df_base$amount[i]
        df_base$count_cumsum[i] = df_base$count[i]
        reset = F
      } else {
        df_base$amount_cumsum[i] = df_base$amount_cumsum[i-1] + df_base$amount[i]
        df_base$count_cumsum[i] = df_base$count_cumsum[i-1] + df_base$count[i]
      }
      if (df_base$amount_cumsum[i] >= 10 & df_base$count_cumsum[i] >= 3) {
        df_base$condition_met[i] = 1
        reset = T
      }
    }
  },
  replications = 100)

gc()
```

> ```
>            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
> Base-R Solution          100    3.89    1.000      3.69      0.0         NA        NA
>   Tidy Solution          100   84.00   21.594     78.65      0.2         NA        NA
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - indeed your `base` solution is much faster than the `dplyr` solution, but for a larger data set (+2 millions observations and +700.000 unique groups/ids) it did unfortunately not work: the `dplyr` solution took 13,55 minutes to compute, while the `base` solution did not finish the calculation even after 1,81 hours. I have marked your answer as correct because I have tested it on a smaller sample and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51965015/9195104) helped me to solve the problem.

```
df <- df %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    nest(data = c(amount, count)) %>%
    mutate(
        data_accumulate = purrr::accumulate(.x = data, .f = function(.x, .y) if (max(.x[1]) < 10 | max(.x[2]) < 3) .x + .y else .y)
    ) %>%
    unnest(cols = c(data_accumulate)) %>%
    rename(amount_cumsum = amount, count_cumsum = count) %>%
    unnest(cols = c(data)) %>%
    mutate(condition_met = case_when(
        amount_cumsum >= 10 & count_cumsum >= 3 ~ 1,
        TRUE ~ 0)
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution, but you can start by looking at the `mess::cumsumbinning` function which is more or less what you're looking for. The thing is `mess::cumsumbinning` accept only one condition, and I don't know how to summarize the `amount` and `count` conditions into one.

For instance, if you're only looking for `count>=3`, you can do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(id,group=cumsumbinning(count,3)) %>% 
  mutate(count_cumsum=cumsum(count))

# A tibble: 18 x 6
# Groups:   id, group [10]
   date       id    amount count group count_cumsum
   <date>     <fct>  <dbl> <dbl> <int>        <dbl>
 1 2020-01-01 A          1     1     1            1
 2 2020-02-01 A          9     3     2            3
 3 2020-03-01 A          5     1     3            1
 4 2020-04-01 A          5     1     3            2
 5 2020-05-01 A          6     4     4            4
 6 2020-06-01 A          2     1     5            1
 7 2020-01-01 B         10     0     5            0
 8 2020-02-01 B          4     0     5            0
 9 2020-03-01 B          8     0     5            0
10 2020-04-01 B         10     0     5            0
11 2020-05-01 B          6     2     5            2
12 2020-06-01 B          5     1     6            1
13 2020-01-01 C          5     1     6            1
14 2020-02-01 C          1     1     6            2
15 2020-03-01 C          6     1     7            1
16 2020-04-01 C          5     2     7            3
17 2020-05-01 C          5     1     8            1
18 2020-06-01 C          5     0     8            1
```

In fact, what you're asking is even more difficult because you want the reset to happen *after* the limit is reached.

I know it's only partial, but I hope it'll help you!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer! I just updated my question with a answer that was deleted by the author. That answer almost solved my problem, and is similar to your approach, but uses the `purrr` package.

Comment: Yes, that answer has the same problem as mine, because `purrr::accumulate` cannot (or I don't know how) use multiple conditions.